# Loading spinner with *ngIf not showing during execution of function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

If trying to show a loading spinner while a function is being executed. I already tried different things, but the spinner won't show.

### This is the HTML:

```
<div class="row pt-3" id="firstRow">
 <div class="col">
  <button class="btn btn-dark back-button">
   <fa name="upload"></fa>
   <span>Load .csv file</span>
  </button>
  <input type="file" #fileImportInput name="File Upload" class="txtFileUpload p-3" (change)="fileChangeListener($event)" accept=".csv" />
    <img class="spinner" *ngIf="loading" src="../../../assets/img/gif-spinner/Spin-2s-200px.gif" />
 </div>
</div>
```

### This is part of the TS-code

```
export class MotionAnalysisComponent implements OnInit {
loading = false;

 fileChangeListener($event: any): void {
   this.loading = true;

   let files = $event.srcElement.files;

   if (this.isCSVFile(files[0])) {
    let input = $event.target;
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);

    reader.onload = () => {
     let csvData = reader.result;
     let csvRecordsArray = (<string>csvData).split(/\r\n|\n/);
     this.csvRecords = this.getDataRecordsArrayFromCSVFile(csvRecordsArray, 4);
   };

   reader.onerror = function () {
    alert('Unable to read ' + input.files[0]);
   };
  } else {
    alert("Please import valid .csv file.");
    this.fileReset();
  }

   this.loading = false;
```

If I comment the "this.loading = false" out within the function, then the spinner will show AFTER the function is executed and will (obviously) not disappear. So how can I make the HTML understand, that the spinner should be shown during the execution of the function?

Comment: Can you show "other part of the function"?

Comment: does fileChangeListener contain async activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow time for the spinner to initialize, you can run the code asynchronously after setting `loading` to `true`. This can be achieved by moving the code inside of a `setTimeout` callback. The `loading` property should be reset at the end of that callback method.

```
fileChangeListener($event) {
  this.loading = true;                    // First, set loading property
  setTimeout(() => {                      // Call setTimeout to run code asynchronously
    let files = $event.srcElement.files;
    if (this.isCSVFile(files[0])) {
      ...
    } else {
      ...
    }
    this.loading = false;                 // Reset loading before leaving callback method
  }, 0);
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2cozbh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for a demo. Please note that you could increase the `setTimeout` delay, if necessary (it is set to 0 ms in the example above).

Comment: I had to modify the code a little bit, but this solved the problem finally :) Thank you so much! Helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that

```
... other part of the function...
```

is a call to an observable or an async function so your

```
this.loading = false;
```

is called straight away.

Without knowing exactly what is in that block of code I can't tell but most likely you need a callback function the executes once the async call has finished to set loading to false.

Comment: I edited the "other part of the function" can you get more insights from that on how I can solve the problem? Thank you so much :)

Comment: Put the this.loading = false; at the end of your onload handler. The line after this.csvRecords = this.getDataRecordsArrayFromCSVFile(csvRecordsArray, 4);

Comment: I implemented this - but the spinner still won't show. As I wrote in another comment - the value of "loading" changed just the way it was supposed to while running the function - but still no spinner :( ...

Answer (score 0):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'm-selector',
  templateUrl: './selector.component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush, <-- add this line
  styleUrls: ['./selector.component.scss']
})
```

add a change detection method

then in your constructor

```
constuctor(
...,
private ref: ChangeDetectorRef <-- add this line
){ }
```

this make you have an access to ask angular to check changes manually

then you can use it, for example:

```
this.loading = true
this.ref.markForCheck()
```

call the ref.markForCheck everytime you change a variable that affect your html with `*ngIf`

this way you will consume less memory as you do not keep listening to a certain variable

but if your variable often changes overtime then it is recommended to use listener

Answer (score 0):

1. It seems that it is necessary to see debug information. So show value of `loading` in your HTML:

   Load .csv file

   ```
    <p>loading {{ loading  }} </p>

    <img class="spinner" *ngIf="loading" 
       src="../../../assets/img/gif-spinner/Spin-2s-200px.gif" />
   </div>
   ```

If you see, that value of `loading` updates correctly, then try to set style:

```
img { 
     width: inherit; 
     height: inherit; 
     position: fixed; 
     top:0; 
     left:0; 
}
```

2. Is it typo? Your `div` tag ends incorrectly: `/div>`

UPDATE:

Try to set `src` of image by template expression:

HTML:

```
<img class="spinner" 
     *ngIf="loading" 
     [src]="imagePath"/>
```

TypeScript:

```
imagePath = '../../../assets/img/gif-spinner/Spin-2s-200px.gif;'
```

Comment: to 2. Only a type ;) already fixed it - to 1. I implemented your line for showing the value of loading. And it changed as it was supposed to. But the spinner didn't show. I also tried your style-setting; unfortunately didn't work either

Comment: @DarkIudeX are you sure that `src` is set correctly? Please, see my updated answer

Comment: Yes, source is correct. Earlier I set the loading to true in the ts-file and the spinner was working

Comment: @DarkIudeX and div is shown? Could you show what styles in your `spinner` class?

Comment: I tried 2 things now: 1. added your div and it was shown - the spinner was not. 2. then I set the loading to always true and reloaded the page und suddenly it was there - so source should be okay